# How to add photo encodings to db with django using face_recognition api?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, face-recognition

I try but it doesn't work...
My model:

```
class Staff(models.Model):

    photo = models.FileField()
    encodings = models.TextField()

    def get_encodings(self):
        enc = face_recognition.face_encodings(self.photo)
        return enc

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.encodings = self.get_encodings()
        super(Staff, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The error which i have when try to add new object

```
__call__(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types 
are supported:
1. (self: dlib.fhog_object_detector, image: array, upsample_num_times: 
int=0) -> dlib.rectangles

Invoked with: <dlib.fhog_object_detector object at 0x0000023D8CD9E570>, 
<FieldFile: photo_2018-12-05_23-09-20.jpg>, 1
```

Comment: How do you load the image? What's the type of the self.photo? 
`print(type(self.photo)) ` what do you get?

Comment: @Peshmerge <class 'django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the file to an image file by using PIL library. 
`face_recognition.face_encodings` expect a numpy array as input

```
 import PIL.Image

class Staff(models.Model):

    photo = models.FileField()
    encodings = models.TextField()

    def get_encodings(self):
        enc = face_recognition.face_encodings(self.read_image_from_file(self.photo))
        return enc

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.encodings = self.get_encodings()
        super(Staff, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

   def read_image_from_file(file):
       return np.array(PIL.Image.open(file))
```

Don't forget to use try and catch when you try to read/open the file/image. My code is just for demonstration, so you must extend it with the needed checks!